# finding guestid in offline documentation?

Tags: powershell, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, powercli

I have a little question thats been bugging me lately.

I am using PowerCLI to create a new VM and I want to use the -guestId parameter to specify the Guest OS.

Is there any built in documentation that lists all the available Guest IDs? It would be far quicker and easier if this was available offline in the documentation than having to open a browser each time to find what I am looking for.

I have tried `get-help new-vm -detailed` but the documentation refers me to to a website.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

ok found it!

```
[System.Enum]::GetNames([VMware.Vim.VirtualMachineGuestOsIdentifier])
```

outputs this:

```
dosGuest
win31Guest
win95Guest
win98Guest
winMeGuest
winNTGuest
win2000ProGuest
win2000ServGuest
win2000AdvServGuest
winXPHomeGuest
winXPProGuest
winXPPro64Guest
winNetWebGuest
winNetStandardGuest
winNetEnterpriseGuest
winNetDatacenterGuest
winNetBusinessGuest
winNetStandard64Guest
winNetEnterprise64Guest
winLonghornGuest
winLonghorn64Guest
winNetDatacenter64Guest
winVistaGuest
winVista64Guest
windows7Guest
windows7_64Guest
windows7Server64Guest
windows8Guest
windows8_64Guest
windows8Server64Guest
freebsdGuest
freebsd64Guest
redhatGuest
rhel2Guest
rhel3Guest
rhel3_64Guest
rhel4Guest
rhel4_64Guest
rhel5Guest
rhel5_64Guest
rhel6Guest
rhel6_64Guest
centosGuest
centos64Guest
oracleLinuxGuest
oracleLinux64Guest
suseGuest
suse64Guest
slesGuest
sles64Guest
sles10Guest
sles10_64Guest
sles11Guest
sles11_64Guest
nld9Guest
oesGuest
sjdsGuest
mandrivaGuest
mandriva64Guest
turboLinuxGuest
turboLinux64Guest
ubuntuGuest
ubuntu64Guest
debian4Guest
debian4_64Guest
debian5Guest
debian5_64Guest
debian6Guest
debian6_64Guest
asianux3Guest
asianux3_64Guest
asianux4Guest
asianux4_64Guest
opensuseGuest
opensuse64Guest
fedoraGuest
fedora64Guest
other24xLinuxGuest
other26xLinuxGuest
otherLinuxGuest
other24xLinux64Guest
other26xLinux64Guest
otherLinux64Guest
solaris6Guest
solaris7Guest
solaris8Guest
solaris9Guest
solaris10Guest
solaris10_64Guest
solaris11_64Guest
os2Guest
eComStationGuest
eComStation2Guest
netware4Guest
netware5Guest
netware6Guest
openServer5Guest
openServer6Guest
unixWare7Guest
darwinGuest
darwin64Guest
darwin10Guest
darwin10_64Guest
darwin11Guest
darwin11_64Guest
vmkernelGuest
vmkernel5Guest
otherGuest
otherGuest64
```

Comment: Is there also a way to get the corresponding OS type like in [this](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-HCX/4.6/hcx-user-guide/GUID-D4FFCBD6-9FEC-44E5-9E26-1BD0A2A81389.html) list?